# Unable to copy IonCube loader files into /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718 in MAC

Tags: php, xampp, lamp, ioncube, phpfox

To setup my php project, I'm trying to copy Ioncube loader files into xampp but I'm getting below error, Can anyone help me?

**sudo cp ioncube_loader_lin_* /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/**

> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_4.1.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_4.2.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_4.3.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_4.3_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_4.4.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_4.4_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.0.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.0_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.1.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.1_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.2.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.2_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.3_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.4_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.5.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.5_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_5.6_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_7.0_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_7.1_ts.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_7.2.so: Permission denied
>
> cp: /Users/arunbharath/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/./ioncube_loader_lin_7.2_ts.so: Permission denied

Comment: Note you only need ONE ionCube Loader file :) The numbers correspond to PHP versions, so you only need the 4.1 file if using PHP 4.1, the 4.2 file if using PHP 4.2 and so on. The _ts version is if PHP is a thread safe build, but most likely it isn't so you need the one without _ts.

Answer (score -1):

Im not 100 percent but if your using cpanel search php click on the php version option make sure running php 7 at least and alo make sure ioncube is ticked. If dont have this option then go to your hosting provider.

Also make sure folders have the correct permissions